# What is different between XP and Win7 when handling a USB composite device?

Tags: windows, usb, embedded

I have developed an USB device using a LPC2148 and the [LPCUSB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpcusb/) USB stack. It works well when I set it as an HID device (a keyboard), but when I set it as a composite device, storage (SD Flash Card) and HID, it only works on Windows XP. I tried in two different Windows 7 computers and both showed me that the device cannot start (code 10 error).

I used two softwares to trace the USB (USBTrace and USBlyzer) and couldn't find what is going on. The device is shown as installed on Win 7, except that it states it can't be started in the hardware device properties. So anyone knows what is different between XP and Win7 when handling a USB composite device?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/E9HqeTDK) is the descriptor in the source code and below is the output from USBlyzer:

```
Connection Status Device connected 
Current Configuration 0 
Speed Full (12 Mbit/s) 
Device Address 5 
Number Of Open Pipes 0 

* Device Descriptor Teleboard
Offset  Field               Size    Value   Description 
0       bLength             1       12h     
1       bDescriptorType     1       01h     Device  
2       bcdUSB              2       0200h   USB Spec 2.0    
4       bDeviceClass        1       00h     Class info in Ifc Descriptors   
5       bDeviceSubClass     1       00h     
6       bDeviceProtocol     1       00h     
7       bMaxPacketSize0     1       40h     64 bytes    
8       idVendor            2       FFFFh       
10      idProduct           2       0003h       
12      bcdDevice           2       0100h   1.00    
14      iManufacturer       1       01h     "Acme"  
15      iProduct            1       02h     "Testboard" 
16      iSerialNumber       1       03h     "ADR2012"   
17      bNumConfigurations  1       01h     

* Configuration Descriptor 1 
Configuration   Descriptor  1   
Offset  Field               Size    Value   Description 
0       bLength             1       09h     
1       bDescriptorType     1       02h     Configuration   
2       wTotalLength        2       0042h       
4       bNumInterfaces      1       02h     
5       bConfigurationValue 1       01h     
6       iConfiguration      1       00h     
7       bmAttributes        1       C0h     Self Powered    
          4..0: Reserved        ...00000            
          5:    Remote Wakeup   ..0.....    No  
          6:    Self Powered    .1......    Yes 
          7:    Reserved        1.......
          (bus-powered for 1.0)     
8       bMaxPower           1       32h     100 mA  

* Interface Descriptor 0/0 Mass Storage, 2 Endpoints
Offset  Field               Size    Value   Description 
0       bLength             1       09h     
1       bDescriptorType     1       04h     Interface   
2       bInterfaceNumber    1       00h     
3       bAlternateSetting   1       00h     
4       bNumEndpoints       1       02h     
5       bInterfaceClass     1       08h     Mass Storage    
6       bInterfaceSubClass  1       06h     SCSI Transparent Command Set    
7       bInterfaceProtocol  1       50h     Bulk-Only Transport 
8       iInterface          1       00h     

* Endpoint Descriptor 85 5 In, Bulk, 64 bytes
Offset  Field               Size    Value   Description 
0       bLength             1       07h     
1       bDescriptorType     1       05h     Endpoint    
2       bEndpointAddress    1       85h     5 In    
3       bmAttributes        1       02h     Bulk    
          1..0: Transfer Type   ......10    Bulk    
          7..2: Reserved        000000..            
4       wMaxPacketSize  2       0040h       64 bytes    
6       bInterval   1   00h     

* Endpoint Descriptor 02 2 Out, Bulk, 64 bytes
Offset  Field               Size    Value   Description 
0       bLength             1       07h     
1       bDescriptorType     1       05h     Endpoint    
2       bEndpointAddress    1       02h     2 Out   
3       bmAttributes        1       02h     Bulk    
          1..0: Transfer Type   ......10    Bulk    
          7..2: Reserved        000000..            
4       wMaxPacketSize      2       0040h   64 bytes    
6       bInterval           1       00h     

* Interface Descriptor 1/0 HID, 1 Endpoint
Offset  Field               Size    Value   Description 
0       bLength             1       09h     
1       bDescriptorType     1       04h     Interface   
2       bInterfaceNumber    1       01h     
3       bAlternateSetting   1       00h     
4       bNumEndpoints       1       01h     
5       bInterfaceClass     1       03h     HID 
6       bInterfaceSubClass  1       00h     
7       bInterfaceProtocol  1       01h     
8       iInterface          1       00h     


* HID Descriptor 
Offset  Field               Size    Value   Description 
0       bLength             1       09h     
1       bDescriptorType     1       21h     HID 
2       bcdHID              2       0110h   1.10    
4       bCountryCode        1       00h     
5       bNumDescriptors     1       01h     
6       bDescriptorType     1       22h     Report  
7       wDescriptorLength   2       0040h   64 bytes    

* Endpoint Descriptor 81 1 In, Interrupt, 32 ms
Offset  Field               Size    Value   Description 
0       bLength             1       07h     
1       bDescriptorType     1       05h     Endpoint    
2       bEndpointAddress    1       81h     1 In    
3       bmAttributes        1       03h     Interrupt   
          1..0: Transfer Type   ......11    Interrupt   
          7..2: Reserved        000000..            
4       wMaxPacketSize      2       0008h   8 bytes 
6       bInterval           1       20h     32 ms   

* String Descriptor 
Offset  Field               Size    Value   Description 
0       bLength             1       04h     
1       bDescriptorType     1       03h     String  
2       wLANGID[0]          2       0409h   English (United States)
```